# JNA Structure StackOverflowError on create

Tags: structure, jna

Hi I have an struct form a c project I need to include in java.

```
struct usb_relay_device_info {
    unsigned char *serial_number;
    char *device_path;
    usb_relay_device_type type;
    usb_relay_device_info* next;};
```

I created a Java class

```
public class RelayInfo extends Structure {

public String device_path;
public RelayInfo next;
public byte[] serial_number;
public RelayType type;

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("device_path", "next", "serial_number", "type");
}}
```

when I try to run my project I get an stackOverwlowError

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:363)
at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:969)
at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:988)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:756)
at com.sun.jna.Native.getDefaultStringEncoding(Native.java:669)
at com.sun.jna.Native.getStringEncoding(Native.java:662)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:177)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:172)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:151)
at relay.RelayInfo.<init>(RelayInfo.java:11)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1773)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.size(Structure.java:1030)
at com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeSize(Native.java:1172)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2072)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2062)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:1105)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:1119)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:172)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:151)
at relay.RelayInfo.<init>(RelayInfo.java:11)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

When I debug it says Method threw'java.lang.StrackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate relay.RelayInfo.toString()

But with JNA i don't need a toString overwrite or?

what is wrong? Anybody an idea?
Thanks vor helbing

Comment: Aren't your fields in the wrong order compared to your C struct? Shouldn't the field order in the Java structure be `"serial_number", "device_path", "type", "next"`?

Comment: already change it and try more . Now  I always get
lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Structure field in class relay.RelayInfo, field name 'type' (interface relay.RelayType): The type "relay.RelayType" is not supported: Native size for type "relay.RelayType" is unknown

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues involved here:  type mapping, and the order of your arguments.

Your Java structure must exactly match the order of the variables in the C structure, as JNA will map the variables by offset.  I understand from the comments that you've already fixed that.

Secondly, you need to be careful with the [type mappings](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md).  While a `char *` can be a String, it also may be a `ByteByReference` so you need to look at the context of the C structure to decide which it is.  I believe you've correctly mapped `String` for the `device_path` but I strongly suspect the `serial_number` is a `ByteByReference` and not the `byte[]` you've defined (which you would need to initialize, anyway; since you don't have a length that's a clue it's not right).  Finally, you've defined a variable of type `RelayType` but haven't written the JNA structure that maps to the corresponding C `usb_relay_device_type`. (EDIT: I see you've clarified that's an `enum`: that maps to an `int`.)

Comment: Thank you my usb_relay_device_type is a enum in C so I created the class like: 
`public interface RelayType {
    public final static int USB_RELAY_DEVICE_ONE_CHANNEL = 1;

    public final static int USB_RELAY_DEVICE_TWO_CHANNEL = 2;

    public final static int USB_RELAY_DEVICE_FOUR_CHANNEL = 4;

    public final static int USB_RELAY_DEVICE_EIGHT_CHANNEL = 8;
}` is that right?

Comment: That works but it's a bit of overkill. You can just define the constants in your other class and declare the `type` variable as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Found my Answer.
Don't know how but it is working

```
public class RelayInfo extends Structure {

/*
struct RelayInfo {
    unsigned char *serial_number;
    char *device_path;
    usb_relay_device_type type;
    usb_relay_device_info* next;
};
*/

public ByteByReference serial_number;
public String device_path;
public int type;
public String next;

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("serial_number", "device_path", "type", "next");
}}
```

Thats how it works for the relay.
Thanks to everybody how tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's node structure like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707280/jna-initialization-of-empty-node-structures/46825180#46825180)
So try to use **RelayInfo** wraped in **PointerByReference**. And keep field **next** as RelayInfo.ByReference