# JNA initialization of empty node structures

Tags: java, jna

I have node structure (it contain value on next same structure).

```
struct Node {
    Node *nextElem;
    Element thisValue;
};
```

I want to pass empty (null) node.ByReference in function that fills it.

```
// C++
Element element = ...; //fills in another function;
Node    *list   = NULL;
AddElementToList(element, &list);
// which declered as
void AddElementToList (Element element, Node * list) {...} 

// Java
Element.ByValue  element = ...; //fills great in another function in the same way ByReference (and reconstructed as ByValue), 
                                //but initialize with trash in Pointers and without recurtion;
Node.ByReference list    = null;
MyDll.INSTANCE.AddElementToList(element, list);
```

So if I use

```
Node.ByReference list = null;
```

I get **Invalid memory access** Error when C++ side try to read **list**, like for any null **Pointer**s.
So I'm trying initialize **list**. But in that case I have to init next node and next and...

Comment: Can you show what the C++ function's declaration is and how you would call it in C++?

Comment: Ah, but it seems you need a pointer to a null pointer to a Node. You are currently passing a null pointer.

Comment: Are you sure AddElementToList is not `(Element element, Node **list)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out solution by wrapping **Node** in **PointerByReference**:

```
// method declaration:
void AddElementToList(Element element, PointerByReference wrapedNodeInPointerByRef);
```

Usage:

```
Element.ByValue element = ...;
PointerByReference list = new PointerByReference();  
MyDll.INSTANCE.AddElementToList(element, list); // yes, Element.ByValue puts in Element

// but to get **Node** from filled PointerByReference you should reparse it like:
Node node = new Node(list.getValue());
```

For that create constructor:

```
public Node (Pointer value) {
 super(value);
 read();
}
```

Constructors for Node.ByValue and Node.ByReference I have get in same way.
This example is simplified version from complicated program with more abstractions, but hope nothing was lost and will helpful for somebody.

Some thinkings:

1. If PointerByReference can has empty instanse, whether Structure.ByReference's can't?
2. Not clear why Element.ByValue works like Element, but when declaration with Element.ByValue it couses to Invalid memory access.